# Radon transform in R

Tags: image, r, image-processing, transformation

I'm looking for an implementation of the radon transform in R. The only one I know of is in the package `PET`. However, it's not giving me the results I expect. I am using the example from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform)

[image]

```
require(png)
require(EBImage)
require(RCurl)
require(PET)

im <- readPNG( getBinaryURL( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e5/Shepp_logan.png/170px-Shepp_logan.png" ) )[,,1]
rad = radon(im)$rData
# Normalize intensity values from 0-1
rad = normalize(rad)

display(t(im))
display(t(rad))
```

I get this image:

[image]

when I expect:

[image]

Am I using the parameters of the function incorrectly? I'm not too familiar with the details of radon transform

Comment: what about transforming the transpose of im , Try to change `radon(im)` by `radon(t(im))`.

Comment: Can you achieve success with the simple 2-squares image shown on the Wikipedia page?  That might be easier to demystify.

Comment: Yep turns out it was a simple transform of `im` as @agstudy mentioned! Not sure how I missed it but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the figures closer: both figures are the same, just shifted 90 degrees.
Recall the Radon transform just does line integrals across different degrees, it shouldn't matter whether it's transposed or not.
Also, the package PET is gone, and there does not seem to be another radon function in cran.
To install the latest PET you can do:

```
devtools::install_github('cran/PET')
```